# How could you find the preimage of an isogeny function?

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptography, group-isomorphism

[image]
How do you know if an isogeny is surjective or not, and how do you tell how many points on E maps to E'? Does the answer lie in the degree of the isogeny function?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: I presume "subjective" is a misprint for surjective. Curves cannot be "surjective" but isogenies can, and that is what the slide is referring to.